# xdebug installation not working

Tags: php, apache, installation, wamp, xdebug

so I added the following line to php.ini:

```
zend_extension="Z:\wamp2\bin\php\php5.3.0\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

xdebug is indeed located in that directory with that filename

I set `report_zend_debug = 0`

restarted wamp, etc

but xdebug still din't show up in phpinfo....

apache error log displays the following:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'Z:/wamp2/bin/php/php5.3.0/ext/php_imagick_ts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
[Mon May 30 19:07:42 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) PHP/5.3.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon May 30 19:07:42 2011] [notice] Server built: Dec 10 2008 00:10:06
[Mon May 30 19:07:42 2011] [notice] Parent: Created child process 4260
Failed loading Z:\wamp2\bin\php\php5.3.0\ext\php_xdebug.dll
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'Z:/wamp2/bin/php/php5.3.0/ext/php_imagick_ts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'Z:/wamp2/bin/php/php5.3.0/ext/php_imagick_ts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
[Mon May 30 19:07:43 2011] [notice] Child 4260: Child process is running
[Mon May 30 19:07:43 2011] [notice] Child 4260: Acquired the start mutex.
[Mon May 30 19:07:43 2011] [notice] Child 4260: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Mon May 30 19:07:43 2011] [notice] Child 4260: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

PHP is version 5.3.0

got the Xdebug 2.1.1 PHP 5.3 VC9 (32 bit) version

Comment: For starters, I'd disable the ImageMagick extension as it doesn't appear to be available

Comment: I don't think it relates directly here, but I found that `zend_extension` does not default to the `extension_dir` but instead is relative to your php installation. So if setting a relative path you need `ext/php_xdebug-2.x.x-5.x-vc9.dll`, e.g., you must add in the `ext/` part.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using PHP as an Apache module, you will need to get xdebug TS (Thread Safe).
If you are using PHP as a CGI process, you will need to get xdebug (NTS - Not Thread Safe).

You will also need to match the builds:

PHP 5.3 VC6 will require xdebug VC6

PHP 5.3 VC9 will require xdebug VC9

Note that your PHP version 5.3.0 is very old, might have outdated API calls, and is generally unstable / full of bugs. Get the latest version: 5.3.6. Or use a wamp package that comes with a matching xdebug version by default.

Here are the lines in mine that once uncommened will load xdebug:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "D:\WampDeveloper\Components\Php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "D:/WampDeveloper/Temp/xdebug"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "D:/WampDeveloper/Temp/xdebug"
```

Answer (score 2):

I've just found that I have to write a full path to the extension, like

```
zend_extension = \usr\local\php5\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.4-vc9.dll
```

Otherwise I've got an error.

Answer (score 1):

just write the full path in `php.ini`

```
zend_extension="C:\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
```